# Problem when adding global privileges to a role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to add CREATE INTEGRATION ON ACCOUNT global privilege to a custom role and my role is ACCOUNTADMIN. But I'm getting "Grant not executed: Insufficient privileges." error. What am I doing wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO1vT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role you have highlighted in red controls the role you're using for the buttons on the ribbon. It's different than the role you're using for the worksheet.

The role you're using for the worksheet is to the right, next to the "Select Warehouse" and "Select Database" options.

In this case, you're using the SECURITYADMIN role for the worksheet. You'll need to change that on the worksheet to use the ACCOUNTADMIN role there.

My recommendation is to use this syntax though to avoid ambiguity:

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
--Do the action you need
use role SYSADMIN; -- Immediately switch away from ACCOUNTADMIN when done using it.
```

Think of ACCOUNTADMIN like root in Linux/Unix. Use it sparingly and get out quickly when done.